# Overloading = operator in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I found out yesterday that it is possible to override operators in python, so after a bit of googling i found out how, but i could not find any way of overloading the "=" sign. There is __set__() but as i understand it, it overloads the sign for attributes in the object, and not for the object itself.

What i want to accomplish is this:

```
F = Foo(1)
G = Foo(2)
F = G #overloaded =
```

So is there a way of overloading "=" for an object in python? (and what is that function called)

Comment: No. You cannot overload the assignment operator in Python. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Comment: You want to overload `=` (assignment) not `==` (equality comparison)?

Comment: In some cases a `property` with a setter could do that. But it only works on object attributes not on "free" variables. There are other options you might want to consider: `setattr()`, a dictionary, the `__dict__` attribute…

Comment: Yes, to basically call a c method when assigning to a different object

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overload =(assign) operator.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the reply!